# Is there a simple way to work out if a specific app has made a call on my router?

Tags: router, iot

I am trying to write some code to control some smart lights in my house. I want to run a project where I connect a motion sensor and run different lighting configurations based on different conditions, after any motion is detected.

I do however want the system to override if someone sets the lighting using the app on their phone/tablet e.g. imagine someone is sleeping in the lounge. I assumed I could look at the router logs and see if a call was made from the app in the last period and if so, ignore the custom lighting script.

Looking through the logs on my router, however, I think I am only seeing device call (rather than specific app calls). Also, I think i am only seeing calls going outside the network - rather than between devices on the network.

Searching on this question has not revealed much.

Can anyone tell me if its possible to have my code scan the logs to see if the call was made from a specific app in a specific time period. Otherwise, if this seems like the wrong way to go about this (because its not possible), I would welcome any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the router will only log incoming/outgoing packets.
Devices inside the network only go through the switch/hub, NOT through the router. No matter that the switch in your case is physically connected with the router, they are two separate/different entities/devices.
If I understand what you want correctly, maybe you could have some luck with a level 3 switch, but I believe the budget will be an issue.
Other proposals: Wireshark monitors ALL network packets, and can give you all details about them (port(s)/IPs, type, etc.). Maybe look in that direction?
Also, some Linux distributions, like Kali Linux, have hundreds of tools in the above direction, but you obviously need to investigate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. So in theory, if i could see the information going through the switch i could be able to filter for where its being sent - the IP addresses of the lights - and where it came from - the IP address of the phone or tablet - and identify if anything was sent in the relevant time period (and then pause the script). Will look into options via wireshark and Kali linux.

Comment: In theory, yes to all. In practice (as always...) it will be more complicated and cumbersome, but those are the principles. Again, Wireshark will show you everything going arount the local network (LAN). Start with this.